# Linear Regression Model

Tags: machine-learning, r, regression, linear-regression, machine-learning-model

I'm taking a course on [Supervised Learning in R: Regression](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/supervised-learning-in-r-regression/what-is-regression?ex=1). There is a section where I'm supposed to predict blood pressure given age and weight. This is was MY approach

```
# Create the formula and print it
fmla <- lm(blood_pressure ~ age + weight, data=bloodpressure)
fmla

# Fit the model: bloodpressure_model
bloodpressure_model <- fmla

# Print bloodpressure_model and call summary() 
bloodpressure_model
summary(bloodpressure_model)
```

It was an incorrect submission. The message error message read -  "The contents of the variable `fmla` aren't correct."

DataCamp's solution was this

```
# bloodpressure is in the workspace
summary(bloodpressure)

# Create the formula and print it
fmla <- blood_pressure ~ age + weight
fmla <- lm(blood_pressure ~ age + weight, data=bloodpressure)

fmla

# Fit the model: bloodpressure_model
bloodpressure_model <- lm(fmla, data = bloodpressure)

# Print bloodpressure_model and call summary()
bloodpressure_model
summary(bloodpressure_model)
```

Both of these models had  the same diagnostic results. What's the issue with MY approach?

Comment: The „correct“ solution looks odd, since fmla is assigned twice. When you do ´lm(...)´ you fit a regression. So in your code fmla already contains the regression results

Answer (score 0):

It should be a bug in their server. The `fmla` variable should have the same contents in your code and in theirs. This is because the last assignment on both scripts is

`fmla <- lm(blood_pressure ~ age + weight, data=bloodpressure)`

Answer (score 0):

The `fmla` is the model *formula*: `fmla <- formula(blood_pressure ~ age + weight)`

So the correct solution should be

```
# bloodpressure is in the workspace
summary(bloodpressure)

# Create the formula and print it
fmla <- formula(blood_pressure ~ age + weight)

fmla

# Fit the model: bloodpressure_model
bloodpressure_model <- lm(fmla, data = bloodpressure)

# Print bloodpressure_model and call summary()
bloodpressure_model
summary(bloodpressure_model)
```